# ¿como colocar un número consecutivo en una matriz bidimencional en java?

Tags: java

Necesito completar una matriz `bidimencional` que imprima los números consecutivos pero solo me imprime la primera serie, es decir:

Para una matriz 4x4

> ```
> 1234
> 1234
> 1234
> 1234
> ```

y lo correcto es que quede de la siguiente manera

> ```
> 1   2   3   4
> 5   6   7   8
> 9  10  11  12
> 13 14  15  16
> ```

El código es el siguiente:

```
package co.edu.uptc;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
        int columnas;
        int filas;
        int i;
        int j;
        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
        columnas =pedir.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
        filas =pedir.nextInt();
        int numPrimos[][] = new int [columnas][filas];

        for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
            int A ;
            for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
                numPrimos[i][j]=j;
                A = numPrimos[i][j];
            } 

        }

        for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
            for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
                System.out.print(numPrimos[i][j]);
            }System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra forma de hacerlo es matemáticamente, ir ubicando cada uno de los elementos, de acuerdo a su divisor y su residuo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int filas = 4;
    int columnas = 4;
    int[][] arreglo = new int[filas][columnas];
    for (int i = 0; i < filas * columnas; i++) {
        arreglo[i/columnas][i%columnas] = i+1;
    }
    // Imprimir
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arreglo[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arreglo[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 buena opción de solución.

Comment: Esa solución se ve interesante.

Answer (score 1):

Los valores serán siempre los mismos dado que al entrar al `for` interno se reinicia el valor de `j`.

Algunos correcciones y/o recomendaciones a su código.

- Recomendación para seguir una lógica , ingresar en primer lugar las filas y luego las columnas.
- La variable `J` siempre inicializará en `0` por cada fila de la matriz es por eso que presenta el resultado que expone.
- Al hacer el `numPrimos.length` obtiene el número de filas , que es lo correcto en el primer `for` pero para el segundo **NO** , imagínese que tiene una matriz `2x4` en los dos `for` estaría accediendo al valor `2` entonces solo asignaría el valor para dos columnas e imprimiría solo dos columnas el resto se mantendría en `0` , para solucionar una opción sería en su segundo `for` que la condición sea `numPrimos[i].length`
- La variable `J` hace la labor de puntero y contador a la vez, pero no sería conveniente usar como valor a asignar para el ejemplo que desea ,para esto se declararía una variable auxiliar `(K)` para llevar el valor en aumento.

**Código completo**

```
Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
int columnas, filas;
System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Filas");
filas =pedir.nextInt();
System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
columnas =pedir.nextInt();
int numPrimos[][] = new int [filas][columnas];
/* Declaración de k en la inicialización del for padre*/
for(int i = 0,k=0;i< numPrimos.length;i++){
   for(int j = 0;j < numPrimos[i].length;j++)
      numPrimos[i][j]=++k;
}
/* Imprimir */
for(int i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
   for(int j = 0;j <numPrimos[i].length;j++)
      System.out.print(numPrimos[i][j] + "\t");
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```